# Mongodb Error on starting as a service with unkown error

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to start mongodb as a service to start the mongod after OS restarted.

I can start mongodb with

```
$ mongod
```

command and it starts but whenever I try to start with

```
$service mongod start
```

but it gives like this error

```
root@sahin:~# service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-01-23 21:35:51 +03; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 43296 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 43296 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 23 21:35:51 sahin systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jan 23 21:35:51 sahin systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 23 21:35:51 sahin systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 23 21:35:51 sahin systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Configurations are like this

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Can you see something that couses this?

Comment: Did you check the log file created at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log ?

Comment: I did and log file is empty. Whenever I try to start mongod as a service or not, it'll not log anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command

```
sudo service mongod start
```